# jQuery - Select element with specific html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to select a div which has a specific html. Look at my example:

```js
$("#clickMe").click(function(){
    $("div:contains('heinrich')").css("background-color", "limegreen")
});
```

```css
.normal {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;

}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#masterdiv {
  border: 10px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="masterdiv">
 My favorite frends are:
   <div class="red normal" id="div1">
       hans
   </div>
    <div class="blue normal" id="div2">
       franz
   </div>
    <div class="yellow normal" id="div3">
       heinrich
   </div>
</div>

<button id="clickMe">
Clicking me should make only heinrichs div limegreen
</button>
```

**jsFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/fj1brnv8/2/

However, the parent div's color also changes.
Is there a way to only select the element itself, I am not allowed to use ID's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better mention the `className`  in the selector `$("div .normal:contains('heinrich')")`

```js
$("#clickMe").click(function(){
    $("div .normal:contains('heinrich')").css("background-color", "limegreen")
});
```

```css
.normal {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;

}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#masterdiv {
  border: 10px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="masterdiv">
 My favorite frends are:
   <div class="red normal" id="div1">
       hans
   </div>
    <div class="blue normal" id="div2">
       franz
   </div>
    <div class="yellow normal" id="div3">
       heinrich
   </div>
</div>

<button id="clickMe">
Clicking me should make only heinrichs div limegreen
</button>
```

Comment: Great, this works without using ID's like requested. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

Just change the root selector.

**UPDATE**

Select every `div` and use the [filter method](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Clone the `div` you're filtering, select all the children (nested divs), remove them then "come back" to the parent `cloned div` and retrieve the text.

Having the text, compare the contents with the text you're searching.

```js
$("#clickMe").click(function(){
    $("div").filter(function(idx, val) {
        return /heinrich/gi.test($(this).clone().children().remove().end().text());
    }).css("background-color", "limegreen")
});
```

```css
.normal {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;

}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#masterdiv {
  border: 10px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="masterdiv">
 My favorite frends are:
   <div class="red normal" id="div1">
       hans
   </div>
    <div class="blue normal" id="div2">
       franz
   </div>
    <div class="yellow normal" id="div3">
       heinrich
   </div>
</div>

<button id="clickMe">
Clicking me should make only heinrichs div limegreen
</button>
```

Comment: @Black Updated answer

Comment: Great job! Good solution

Comment: Instead of the `div` selector alone, you could narrow the selector to your original `div:contains('heinrich')`

Answer (score 2):

In your exable should be different selector:

```
$("#masterdiv > div:contains('heinrich')")
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do

```
    $("#clickMe").click(function(){ 
$("#masterdiv  div:contains('heinrich')").css("background-color", "limegreen")
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't want to use ids I can suggest you to try this.

```
   $('div > div:contains(heinrich)').css("background-color", "limegreen")
```

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g50cfqzw/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#clickMe").click(function(){
        var html_trg="heinrich";
    $('.normal').each(function(i,u){
            var divtxt=$(u).html();
        divtxt=$.trim(divtxt);
            if(divtxt==html_trg){
          $(u).css("background-color", "limegreen");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this it will work

```
  $("#clickMe").click(function(){
        $("div#masterdiv").find('div.normal:contains(heinrich)').css("background-color", "limegreen")
    });
```